# How to duplicate an object?

Tags: delphi, properties, indy, cloning, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm on Delphi 11.

I need to create a new instance of a `TIdMessage` and `TIDSmtp`, simply by copying all properties from another `TIdMessage` and `TIDSmtp`. What's the best way to do it besides manually assigning the properties you need one by one?

```pas
var 
  newIdMessage : TIDMessage;
  newIDSmtp : TIDSmtp;
begin
  newIdMessage := TIDMessage.create;
  newIdSmtp := TIDSmtp.create;

  // something like this:
  newIdMessage.copyPropertiesFrom(form1.IdMessage1);
  newIdSmtp.copyPropertiesFrom(form1.IdSmtp1);
end;
```

Comment: Create an instance of TIdMessageClient and use the ProcessMessage method

Comment: @DaveNottage I don't understand how that answers the question. `TIdMessageClient.ProcessMessage()` is intended for reading an email from a file/socket, not for cloning objects in memory.

Comment: @delphirules like most Delphi objects, most Indy components do not directly support cloning themselves (ie, by overriding `TPersistent.Assign/To()`), so you have to copy their properties one at a time, either manually or via RTTI. For `published` properties, at least, the simplest solution is to use a `TMemoryStream` with its `WriteComponent()` and `ReadComponent()` methods to save an object to an in-memory DFM and then read it back out into another object. Other solutions exist, but they require more work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's the same process that TIdMessage uses for LoadFromStream

Comment: @DaveNottage only because `TIdMessage`'s logic is not implemented in the right place. The logic is in `TIdMessageClient` which is a base class of the SMTP/POP3/IMAP components. `TIdMessage` creates a temp `TIdMessageClient` to read/write emails via a stream/file. But I still wouldn't suggest your solution. You didn't explain how to create the data that `ProcessMessage()` would read. It would be far easier to just use `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` and `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` instead, but that is not a true clone of all of the properties. And, you can't duplicate `TIdSMTP` that way anyway.

Comment: :) Funny title now: `How to duplicate an object? [duplicate]`

Comment: @AmigoJack Inception !